# How do I properly convert XML to JS Objects while properly containing sections of CDATA

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, rss

I am trying to build an RSS reader for 500px.com... I am trying to grab and sort all the elements of the xml file into JS objects using this function:

```
function XML2jsobj(node) {

var data = {};

// append a value
function Add(name, value) {
    if (data[name]) {
        if (data[name].constructor != Array) {
            data[name] = [data[name]];
        }
        data[name][data[name].length] = value;
    }
    else {
        data[name] = value;
    }
};

// element attributes
var c, cn;
for (c = 0; cn = node.attributes[c]; c++) {
    Add(cn.name, cn.value);
}

// child elements
for (c = 0; cn = node.childNodes[c]; c++) {
    if (cn.nodeType == 1) {
        if (cn.childNodes.length == 1 && cn.firstChild.nodeType == 3 || cn.childNodes.length == 1&& cn.firstChild.nodeType === 4) {
            // text value
            Add(cn.nodeName, cn.firstChild.nodeValue);
        }
        else {
            // sub-object
            Add(cn.nodeName, XML2jsobj(cn));
        }
    }
}

return data;
```

}
Everything works all dandy and properly gives me an array of every available described image, however, It does not give me the a ref that is wrapped around a CDATA tag as shown here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUIQw.jpg

The item array(bottom picture) properly gives me all the available pictures; however in the description tag, it gives me an undefined object as opposed to giving me the "img src =..." that I'm looking for.. Here's my start up code if it gives any further information: url = https://500px.com/popular.rss

```
var url = 500px.com/popular.rss;
function startApp(url){
var url1 = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20%3D%20'"+url+"'";
function createTree(){
    $.get(url1, function (data) {
        console.log("data:",data);
        var items = XML2jsobj(data.getElementsByTagName('channel')[0]);
        console.log("Data / Channel:",data.getElementsByTagName('channel')[0]);
        var test = data.getElementsByTagName('channel')[0];

        responseFeed = items;
        console.log("items:",items);


    });
}
createTree();
```

}

Comment: Are you trying to get `#comment` nodes within a `document`?

Comment: Im trying to pull out : "<img src="https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/215312191/m%3D900/c4622e09b42b487114860cf832a11ac7">"
from the channel.item[0].description

Comment: No results are returned from query, here

Comment: As you can see in the console; link, guid, and pubDate all retain their proper values whereas description sort of just explodes.

Comment: No results are returned from `url1`, here

Comment: url = https://500px.com/popular.rss

Comment: url1 = https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20%3D%20'"+url+"'"

Comment: guest271314: is there anyway we can chat? I can send you the live version of the website which can give you the console info you need.

Comment: You can get the `.textContent` of all `<description>` elements, then use `RegExp` to match only `<img>` portion of string, convert matched string to jQuery object or `DOM` element to get `.src` of  `<img>`, see Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.text()` to get `.textContent` of all `description` elements, `.match()` with `RegExp` `/<img\s.+>(?=<)/g` to get an array of `<img>` elements as text, which can be converted to jQuery objects or elements using `jQuery()`

```js
function startApp(url) {

  var url1 = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20%3D%20'" + url + "'";

  function createTree() {
    $.get(url1, function(data) {

      var images = $(data.documentElement)
        .find("description")
        .text()
        .match(/<img\s.+>(?=<)/g);
        
      var srcs = $.map(images, function(img) {
                   return $(img).attr("src")
                 });
                 
      console.log(images, srcs);
      
    });
  }
  createTree();
}

startApp("http://500px.com/popular.rss")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```